# Unable to use OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken in a ReportPhishingCommandSurface

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

In a POC using the new extension point ReportPhishingCommandSurface, I try to get an access token (in order to submit graph API call), however the method always return "SSO failed with "5001" error code." with no addiotional information.

I used the Microsoft example available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/extensionpoint?view=word-js-preview#reportphishingcommandsurface-preview to have a running example and juste modified the called function to call OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken

Additional information:

I have two applications which are identically configured in azure portal. One which triggers OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken from a standard addin when a user clicks on a button -> this works as expected. The other using the ReportPhishingCommandSurface is getting "SSO failed with "5001".

From the comment below:

1. I do see a request to  /.well-known/microsoft-officeaddins-allowed.json which contains the following entries:

```
{
    "allowed":
    [
        "https://localhost:3000/command/command.js",
        "https://localhost:3000/command/command.html",
    ]
}
```

2. The URLs are allowed in the "singe page application" configuration tab in Azure:

[image: azure sinple page app]

3. The manifest contains the "WebApplicationInfo" section:

```
 <WebApplicationInfo>
        <Id>[redacted]</Id>
        <Resource>api://localhost:3000/[redacted]</Resource>
        <Scopes>
          <Scope>openid</Scope>
          <Scope>profile</Scope>
          <Scope>email</Scope>
          <Scope>User.Read</Scope>
          <Scope>Mail.Read</Scope>
          <Scope>Mail.ReadWrite</Scope>
          <Scope>Mail.Send</Scope>
        </Scopes>
      </WebApplicationInfo>
```

IN addition here is the code which call getAccessToken:

```
const defaultSSO = {
    allowSignInPrompt: false,
    allowConsentPrompt: false,
};

function onSpamReport(event) {
 

    const options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(defaultSSO));

    // Begin promise chain.
    return OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken(options).then((accessToken) =>
    {
        console.log('getAccessToken done');
        console.log('accesstoken: ' + accessToken); //<- we never reach this point

       ...
```

In the log file, I get the following entries:

```
20/09/2023 15:13:59 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] SDX Control is ready!       
20/09/2023 15:13:59 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] onSpamReport        
20/09/2023 15:13:59 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] MailboxHostExecuteApi invoked!      
20/09/2023 15:13:59 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] RunLaunchEventHandlerFunctionWithData was invoked with funcName = onSpamReport          
20/09/2023 15:13:59 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] callWebServerAPI(POST, https://localhost:3000/report_phishing)      
20/09/2023 15:13:59 Verbose Runtime [Console] [Log] MailboxHostExecuteApi invoked!      
20/09/2023 15:13:59 Monitorable WebApplicationInfo  SSO failed with "5001" error code.
```

Answer (score 0):

ReportPhishingCommandSurface in Win32 Outlook, actually has the same limitations/features as Event Based Add-ins.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest#event-based-activation-behavior-and-limitations

One thing that is needed is the .well-known resource. URI see this here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-sso-in-event-based-activation

let us know if this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: No it is not working, The URL used by the manifest are in the /.well-known/microsoft-officeaddins-allowed.json file and I see the request from the plugin to this file.

Comment: Is there a way to have more details on what caused the "5001" error code ? It looks like a blackbox with no additional information.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. We've verified that this should be working. We acknowledge that the error reporting could be improved. however, if everything is set up correctly it should work. Some common pitfalls. Make sure you have registered your app with AAD, and your manifest contains the appropriate "WebApplicationInfo" section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2

also make sure your .json file is accessible (though it sounds like you already did that). But for example in Azure Web Apps, you must configure it to allow .json files.

Comment: Other issues usually revolve around incorrect appIds in the manifest, or errors in the WebApplicationInfo section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Edited the main message with additional information, maybe it will help.

 You could explains what do you mean with " Azure Web Apps, you must configure it to allow .json files" ?

Comment: The symptoms you describe here really seem to indicate that the .well-known file is not accessible. This is a common problem on Azure Websites: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/africaapps/how-to-serve-static-json-files-from-a-windows-azure-website I would try to access your .well-known file directly in a browser to make sure it is accessible.

Comment: However you did mention that you can see the request to the file (how did you verify the request?). You can also turn on Runtime logging, and check the log to see if that contains any clues as to what may be going on here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtime-logging

Comment: I log every requests to the web server. When i open outlook,, I see the first request to the script file linked in the manifest then to the .well-known file:

15:07:08.774 info   GET /command/command.js -> 200 content-length:8740 
15:07:08.789 info   GET /.well-known/microsoft-officeaddins-allowed.json -> 200 content-length:138

Comment: Runtime logging is enabled but does not much output (see main message)

Comment: I tested the same code in a "standard" addin via a button in taskpane. In this case everything worked perfectly and I got a token back.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. The only known issue so far with this is the well-known file. Can you access the well-known file by just navigating to it in a web browser. (though I admit your logs seem to indicate it's working) Is it possible the format of the well-known file is off? Is it possible for you to try this outside of localhost and an actual web server?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to see if this is also failing for other Event Based Add-ins (like OnMessageCompose) You should just be able to add that entry to the manifest, and point it to a similar function in the same file.

Comment: Could you also try only having the .js files in the well-known resource? and not the .html file?

Comment: Can you also confirm that all of these steps are set up correctly? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/use-sso-to-get-office-signed-in-user-token?tabs=vs2019

Comment: Yes i can access the well-known file. I also tried to change it and to only have  the js file in it but it does not fix the problem.

Comment: If I try to add an Event based section in the manifest, it is never triggered (and no error in the logs).

Comment: All the steps from the "Use SSO to get the identity of the signed-in user" are configured correctly since I'm able to get a token if the same script runs fom a Taskpane button instead of from the spam report button

Comment: @Plann1n3 is this your same issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3759 Thanks for helping us diagnose this issue. It looks like there is a bug that the product team will need to fix. They were able to repro with your help, and in the github post there is a temporary workaround.

Comment: Hello, yes it also my issue :)